# one-way ANOVA model

Tags: statistics, anova

In the one-way ANOVA model, the model variation SSM is equal to the
between-group variation SSB.
I found that 
SSE=SST-SSB => SSB=SST-SSE
And that SSM is the difference of STT and SSE => SSM=SST-SSE
SSB=SSM 
But this holds for ANOVA does it make a difference if I am looking for one-way ANOVA?

Comment: You will find [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) a number of hints on how to get started when you have no clue about some question. Do not expect people here to do your homework for you without you showing the slightest bit of efforts.

Comment: I have edited it . can you help me now?

Comment: You write "I found that..." where did you find that? I'm really curious. Usually the notation SSW should pop up somewhere.

Comment: in my lecture notes

Comment: So your lecture notes use two different notations for the exact same thing?

Comment: is what I understood

Comment: Then yes, by definition, both are equal in this case. It would be in fact more correct to say that "SSM" is a generic name that you will find in different contexts (such as ANOVA, regression, etc.), and that in the particular context of one-way ANOVA, the sum of squares of the model is the Between Groups sum of squares.

Comment: If you ever need to ask again a question like this, a better way to get help fast would be "I found in my lecture notes that in the one-way ANOVA model, SSM and SSB denote the same thing; I find this confusing, why are we using two different names for the same thing?"

Answer (score 1):

This answer may not help almost two years later...

When calculating the sum of squares there is definitely a difference depending on the number of groups in the model.

Let's say you were comparing test scores between two different classes of students. To find the sum of squared error (SSE) for **one-way ANOVA**:

SS<sub>ERROR</sub> = SS<sub>TOTAL</sub> - SS<sub>CLASSES</sub>

Since the rules of addition and subtraction apply:

SS<sub>TOTAL</sub> = SS<sub>CLASSES</sub> + SS<sub>ERROR</sub>

SS<sub>CLASSES</sub> = SS<sub>TOTAL</sub> - SS<sub>ERROR</sub>

For a **two-way ANOVA**, you need another group. The second group represents students how that either sat in the front half of the classroom and those that sat in the back half. The group is named 'seating' for simplicity. Now to calculate the residual sum of squares:

SS<sub>ERROR</sub> = SS<sub>TOTAL</sub> - (SS<sub>CLASSES</sub> + SS<sub>SEATING</sub>)

Since the rules of addition and subtraction apply:

SS<sub>TOTAL</sub> = (SS<sub>CLASSES</sub> + SS<sub>SEATING</sub>) + SS<sub>ERROR</sub>

SS<sub>CLASSES</sub> + SS<sub>SEATING</sub> = SS<sub>TOTAL</sub> - SS<sub>ERROR</sub>